# ¿Cómo utilizar el vector?

Tags: array

Quisiera saber cual es la diferencia entre estos 2 códigos:

```
vector<CCirculo*> arrCirculo;
vector<CCirculo> arrCirculo;
```

Al momento de agregar la única forma en la que puedo hacerlo es haciendo esto

```
CCirculo* objCirculo = new CCirculo();

arrCirculo.push_back(objCirculo);
```

Quisiera saber si se puede agregar utilizando este código:

```
vector<CCirculo> arrCirculo;
```

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje?

Comment: Estoy utlizando c++